# How to use tf_remap?

Tags: ros, remap

I have a `rosbag` in which a `/tf` topic is recorded.

I need to remap all `tf` frames in that bag which refer to the frame named `/world` to refer to a new frame named `/vision`. I tried the following but it's unfortunately not working:

```
rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /world, new: /vision}]'
```

Am I missing something?

I have also tried to do it from a *launch file*:

```xml
    <launch>
      <node pkg="tf" type="tf_remap" name="tf_remapper" output="screen">
        <rosparam param="mappings">
          - {old: "/world",
             new: "/vision"}
        </rosparam>
      </node>
    </launch>
```

Same result...

I found people saying that, in addition to running the `tf_remap` node, `rosbag` should be run as follows:

```
rosbag play x.bag /tf:=/tf_old
```

Also did that... still not working.

The `tf_frame`s are still referring to `/world` rather than `/vision`.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

---

#### Edit

This is to clarify more what I am trying to achieve:

What I want is to remap all the frames recorded in the bag and referring to `/world`, and make them refer to `/vision` instead. There should be no `/world` frame in the remapped output of the bag. Somewhere else in the code, I will define the frame named `/world` and its relation to `/vision`.

Comment: Have you looked at the ros `<remap>` tag in roslaunch? http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the contents of the bag file using the rosbag python/c++ API. Here is an example with python that would just replace any instance of /world with /vision in your bag's recorded /tf msgs.

```python
import rosbag
from copy import deepcopy
import tf

bagInName = '___.bag'
bagIn = rosbag.Bag(bagInName)
bagOutName = '___fixed.bag'
bagOut = rosbag.Bag(bagOutName,'w')
with bagOut as outbag:
    for topic, msg, t in bagIn.read_messages():
        if topic == '/tf':
            new_msg = deepcopy(msg)
            for i,m in enumerate(msg.transforms): # go through each frame->frame tf within the msg.transforms
                if m.header.frame_id == "/world":
                    m.header.frame_id = "/vision"
                    new_msg.transforms[i] = m
                if m.child_frame_id == "/world":
                    m.child_frame_id = "/vision"
                    new_msg.transforms[i] = m

            outbag.write(topic, new_msg, t)
        else:
            outbag.write(topic, msg, t)

bagIn.close()
bagOut.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [tf_remap](http://wiki.ros.org/tf_remapper_cpp) command seems correct. However, you're one step away from the solution: Briefly described, tf_remap listens to a tf topic, makes your desired changes, and then publishes the transformation to a new tf topic. These topics default to tf_old`and`/tf`, respectively.

So, you first start your tf_remap node as you did in your question.

```
rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /world, new: /vision}]'
```

Then, you start playing your rosbag, remapping the `/tf` topic to `/tf_old`

```
rosbag play ... /tf:=/tf_old
```

Now, `rosbag play` publishes the messages via the `/tf_old` topic. The tf_remap node subscribes to the `/tf_old` topic and publishes the altered transformations (with the replaced frames) on the `/tf` topic.